# Can't do "yum update" in Fedora running in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, fedora, ipv6

I just made a clean install of Fedora 20 as a VM in VirtualBox. I set up the VM to use NAT as part of the network configuration in VirtualBox.

At first I could ping google.com, but could not browse using Firefox. And when I tried to execute `yum update` I got the following error:

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Error: Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: fedora/20/x86_64. Please verify its path and try again
```

Then I disabled IPv6 in the network settings, and I also disabled this option in Firefox. As a result I was able to browse using Firefox, but I still keep getting the error when doing `yum update`.

When I do `URLGRABBER_DEBUG=1 yum check-update` I get:

```
2013-12-20 11:33:35,612 attempt 1/10: https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-20&arch=x86_64
2013-12-20 11:33:35,612 opening local file "/var/cache/yum/x86_64/20/fedora/metalink.xml.tmp" with mode wb
* Adding handle: conn: 0x1c896d0
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 9 (0x1c896d0) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Could not resolve host: mirrors.fedoraproject.org
* Closing connection 9
2013-12-20 11:33:45,169 exception: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrors.fedoraproject.org"
2013-12-20 11:33:45,169 retrycode (14) not in list [-1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], re-raising
Error: Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: fedora/20/x86_64. Please verify its path and try again
```

But when I do `ping mirrors.fedoraproject.org` I get:

```
ping mirrors.fedoraproject.org
PING wildcard.fedoraproject.org (209.132.181.16) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from wildcard.fedoraproject.org (209.132.181.16): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=104 ms
64 bytes from wildcard.fedoraproject.org (209.132.181.16): icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=115 ms
64 bytes from wildcard.fedoraproject.org (209.132.181.16): icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=135 ms
```

The result of `nslookup mirrors.fedoraproject.org` is:

```
Server:     192.168.0.1
Address:    192.168.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
mirrors.fedoraproject.org   canonical name = wildcard.fedoraproject.org.
Name:   wildcard.fedoraproject.org
Address: 209.132.181.16
Name:   wildcard.fedoraproject.org
Address: 67.203.2.67
Name:   wildcard.fedoraproject.org
Address: 213.175.193.206
Name:   wildcard.fedoraproject.org
Address: 140.211.169.197
Name:   wildcard.fedoraproject.org
Address: 152.19.134.146
Name:   wildcard.fedoraproject.org
Address: 80.239.156.215
Name:   wildcard.fedoraproject.org
Address: 66.35.62.166
Name:   wildcard.fedoraproject.org
Address: 66.135.62.201
Name:   wildcard.fedoraproject.org
Address: 85.236.55.6
```

I tried using the bridged adapter option in VirtualBox, but I got the same errors.

I followed the suggestion of enabling the DNS proxy in NAT mode, but the same problem persists (I can still browse in Firefox, but yum cannot resolve the host mirrors.fedoraproject.org). Now the `ifconfig` commands shows this:

```
p2p1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fea4:a4c6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:a4:a4:c6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 723  bytes 695639 (679.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 628  bytes 77437 (75.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 19  base 0xd020
```

An the `cat /etc/resolv.conf` shows this:

```
nameserver 10.0.2.3
```

And finally, I tried "Using the host's resolver as a DNS proxy in NAT mode" and the issue was finally fixed.

Comment: what is the result you have for `nslookup mirrors.fedoraproject.org` ?

Comment: Switch to a bridged network config and test if that works better.

Comment: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#nat-adv-dns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed the suggestion made by Michael using these two steps:

[Enabling DNS proxy in NAT mode](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#nat-adv-dns)

[Using the host's resolver as a DNS proxy in NAT mode](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#nat_host_resolver_proxy)

Now I am able to browse and use `yum` successfully.